# @import not working in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm having a style.css file which is having the following code:

```
@import url("bootstrap.css");                       
@import url("icons.css");
@import url("plugins/revolutionslider.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700');
```

and below some more css code. Now I'm trying to compile css file with Laravel Mix, so below is my  `webpack.mix.js` file's code:

```
    mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/custom/css/style.css',
    'resources/assets/custom/css/colors/main.css'
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Now, after running `npm run dev`, instead of importing all those css files, it's below is the output which I get on compiled file `app.css`

```
@import url("bootstrap");
@import url("icons.css");
@import url("plugins/revolutionslider.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700');
```

So why is it not importing the code inside those files? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue where my google fonts were not being imported.

Apparently @imports must come before anything else, except @charset:

> The @import CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except @charset rules;

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

So my solution was to ensure all my @imports (currently just Google fonts) are mixed FIRST:

```
mix.styles([
'public/css/vendor/google-fonts.css',
'public/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css',
'public/css/custom.css'
], 'public/css/app.css')
.version();
```

Not sure if this 100% applies but it solved the issue for me.

Comment: This fixed for me. Still not sure why my mix.sass() has to become before my js, but it works so I will take that as a win!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this and it's a bit annoying it's not mentioned in the docs although I suppose this is intended as a very basic operation.

A fairly full proof method is to just create a `.scss` file and import all the required scripts you're concatenating.

Then run this single `.scss` file through `mix.sass()`

e.g. make a file `all.scss` within `resources/assets/custom/css`

```
@import 'style.css',
@import 'colors/main.css'
```

Then add to `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/custom/css/all.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
```

`mix.scss()` will move any `@import url()` statements to the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of mix it does not work so simple, so I had to import all partial scss files in additionalData property. Here is my example:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            additionalData: `@import "@/_variables.scss";
                            @import "@/_mixins.scss";
                            @import "@/_extends.scss";
                            @import "@/_general.scss";`
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/sass'),
            '~': path.resolve('/resources/js'),
            'Vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        }
    },
    output: {
        chunkFilename: '[name].js?id=[chunkhash]',
    },
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .copyDirectory('resources/images', 'public/images');
```